# cmake or g++: include dll libraries

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, g++

I have been trying to write a code in C++ under Windows, that uses a third party library (I have .dll files, .lib files and .h files). I tried so many configurations in CMAKE (I am using CLion), but none of them worked! still cannot find the library. So I decided to use the plain `g++` command. Still nothing!! The image below shows file tree
[image: My project file tree]

This is my latest cmakelists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(tf_cert_mngr)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(LIBRARIES_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/openssl)
include_directories(src)
link_directories(${LIBRARIES_DIR}/lib)
include_directories(${LIBRARIES_DIR}/include)
#include_directories(include openssl\\include openssl\\lib2)

set(SOURCE_FILES src/Certificate.cpp src/tf-cert-mngr.cpp)
set(HEADER_FILES include/Certificate.h include/tf-cert-mngr.h)
find_package(ssl )
find_package(crypto)
add_executable(tf_cert_mngr ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
target_link_libraries(tf_cert_mngr libssl.lib libcrypto.lib)
```

its result:

```
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable tf_cert_mngr.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lssl
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot 
find -lcrypto
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\tf_cert_mngr.dir\build.make:101: recipe for target 'tf_cert_mngr.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [tf_cert_mngr.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:71: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/tf_cert_mngr.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/tf_cert_mngr.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/tf_cert_mngr.dir/rule] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:83: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/tf_cert_mngr.dir/rule' 
failed
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'tf_cert_mngr' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [tf_cert_mngr] Error 2
```

and this is the latest g++ command I used:

```
g++ src\tf-cert-mngr.cpp src\Certificate.cpp -Iinclude -I openssl\include  -L openssl\lib -llibcrypto.lib -l libssl.lib -o tester
```

its result:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibcrypto.lib
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibssl.lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: " still cannot find the library". You should add to your post the evidence that leads to you make this unclear statement.

Comment: Please include the output of ``make VERBOSE=1``.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the documentation for FindOpenSSL.cmake. This is the script that is called internally when you call:

`find_package(OpenSSL)` (note that for portability, case is important).

Notice that the script creates two targets:

> This module defines the following IMPORTED targets:
>
> `OpenSSL::SSL`
>
> The OpenSSL ssl library, if found.
>
> `OpenSSL::Crypto`
>
> The OpenSSL crypto library, if found.

So try changing your `CMakeLists.txt` file to read:

```
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

...

target_link_libraries(tf_cert_mngr OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto)
```

Reference: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenSSL.html